# So is it true that HP printer no longer work with Linux at all?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

Here is my conversation with HP regarding scanners:

```
08/30/2013 07:34:15AM   Agent (Janelle M.): "Hello, Ken."
08/30/2013 07:34:22AM   ken schutter: "Hello"
08/30/2013 07:35:06AM   Agent (Janelle M.): "Ken, I appreciate your interest in HP products."
08/30/2013 07:35:40AM   ken schutter: "Hp is my preference for all printers because they work out of the box in linux."
08/30/2013 07:35:57AM   Agent (Janelle M.): "I am very sorry to inform you though, however, our scanners and All-in-one printers with scanning capability do not support Linux anymore."
08/30/2013 07:36:32AM   ken schutter: "Too bad. HPLIP is no longer valid driver?"
08/30/2013 07:36:57AM   Agent (Janelle M.): "Yes, it is no longer a valid driver, Ken. I am sorry."
08/30/2013 07:37:14AM   ken schutter: "I will try elsewhere. Thanks"
08/30/2013 07:37:27AM   Session Ended
```

Comment: I can confirm that scanning on an HP Officejet 6600 still works perfectly fine using xsane 0.999 on ubuntu 19.10 (through connected usb cable). HPLIP version installed is 3.19.6. printing works without problems as well.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell that simply means that HP does no longer officially support Linux drivers. That's far from saying that HP printers don't work on Linux.

Looking at HPLIP project news page, updates are coming at constant pace http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/news.html

Before buying a new printer/scanner search "linux [printer-model-number]" to check if it is working on linux. That is a common practice for any device actually, not only printers.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking as an Ex HP Third level support person, this is BS.  I have multiple HP printers at work working with Ubuntu better that they worked with Windows.

> HP is investing resources in open source efforts to improve the
>   support for devices within Linux, including HP printers. Currently HP
>   provides Linux printing support for over 1,200 HP printers. These
>   pages feature information to help guide you regarding the current
>   status of support for HP printers with Linux, as well as a list of
>   sites for additional information. This site will provide ongoing
>   updates as HP continues to expand its commitment to Open Source and
>   Linux.<sup>[HP](http://www.hp.com/wwsolutions/linux/products/printing_imaging/index.html)</sup>

[HP Linux Imaging and Printing](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html)

For [supported Printers](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/supported_devices/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as the recent purchaser of an OfficeJet 6600 (a fairly new printer), I don't think this is true. The printer works fine, the scanner works fine and I've even automated the document feeder into a little document store application I've written. It's all fine.

What's more is there have been several HP-pushed HPLIP driver updates while I've been using them, adding support for new printers and fixing bugs in old ones. We're up to 3.13.8. That doesn't look like a company winding down support.

One feature that is missing is the Scan-To-Computer function (you stand at the printer, feed in a document and press scan on the printer and a new document magically appears on your computer). They haven't implemented that in HPLIP. That might be what the person you were speaking to was talking about... Maybe.

I don't want to be too quick to decide. I'm just a customer. I'd probably talk to a few more people before making my mind up though. Have a word with the HPLIP developers and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

I have had no issues with using HPLIP. Their installer is easy on Ubuntu. If you need instructions, try this:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

Comment: I would recommend against those instructions. For Ubuntu, you have packages and it's available in the Software Centre. No need to install from source!

Answer (score 1):

I bought a new HP printer(Deskjet 2515 AIO of the series 2510) and just completed installing it using  hplip-3.13.8 from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html and is working pretty fine.

The scan quality using xsane or other software is lower than the windows counterpart, but acceptable.

So, HP still works on Linux.
 Maybe the agent you talked to have no knowledge about Linux !!
Maybe she is either Windows or Mac user ???

Comment: FYI, I can confirm that Ubuntu 12.04 (with the default hplip-3.12.2) does not support the HP printer(Deskjet 2515 AIO of the series 2510).